# It would really be $f|_{I^n}$ a homeomorphism onto $I^n$ and $f (I^n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am studying an article that deals with the proof of [invariance of the domain theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) In the article the following statement is made:

> Since $I^n$ is a compact space, the map $f|_{I^n}$ is a homeomorphism from $I^n$ to $f(I^n)$.

In this part of the article,

- $I^n$ is the n-dimensional cube $[-a,a]^n$ and $a>0$,
- $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is an injective continuous map,
- $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open,
- $I^n\subset U$.

But this statement is not clear to me. It is not clear to me what the topology or the open sets of the compact $I^n$" are. Likewise, it is not clear who the open sets or topology of $f(I^n)$ are.

> **My question.**
>   How can I prove this statement and make it clear who are the topologies of $I^n$ and $f(I^n)$ that makes the constraint $f|_{I^n}$ a homeomorphism onto $I^n$ and $f (I^n)$?

Comment: As subspaces of the ambient Euclidean spaces.

Comment: A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism

Answer (score 1):

Here, $I^n$ and $f(I^n)$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. That is, their topology is the topology induced by $\mathbb{R}^n$. And $f|_{I^n}$ is a homeomorphism because $f$ is continuous and injective and $I^n$ is compact.